# How fix Error:Execution failed for task ':android:processDebugResources'?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':android:processDebugResources'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

What I've done, and that did not help:
I closed and opened AS, cleaning project and rebuilt.

full logs:

```
    Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :android:generateDebugSources, :android:mockableAndroidJar, :android:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :android:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
:android:clean
:core:clean
:desktop:clean UP-TO-DATE
:ios:clean UP-TO-DATE
:android:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:android:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:android:checkDebugManifest
:android:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:core:compileJava
Warning:[options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
1 warning
:core:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:core:classes
:core:jar
:android:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2411Library
:android:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72411Library
:android:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42411Library
:android:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2411Library
:android:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds921Library
:android:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAdsLite921Library
:android:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase921Library
:android:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement921Library
:android:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesClearcut921Library
:android:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGass921Library
:android:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks921Library
:android:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAds921Library
:android:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics921Library
:android:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl921Library
:android:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon921Library
:android:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCore921Library
:android:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid921Library
:android:prepareDebugDependencies
:android:compileDebugAidl
:android:compileDebugRenderscript
:android:generateDebugBuildConfig
:android:mergeDebugShaders
:android:compileDebugShaders
:android:generateDebugAssets
:android:mergeDebugAssets
:android:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:android:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: D:\Android Project\LibGdx\MaGame\android\google-services.json
:android:generateDebugResources
:android:mergeDebugResources
:android:processDebugManifest
:android:processDebugResources FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':android:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\Programm\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 10.08 secs
Information:1 error
Information:1 warning
Information:See complete output in console
```

Gradle-android:

```
   android {
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'
    compileSdkVersion 23
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "upwardteam.pavel.game"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    lintOptions {

        checkReleaseBuilds false

    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.2.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives() {
    file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/arm64-v8a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86_64/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

    configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
        def outputDir = null
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-arm64-v8a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/arm64-v8a")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86_64.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86_64")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
        if (outputDir != null) {
            copy {
                from zipTree(jar)
                into outputDir
                include "*.so"
            }
        }
    }
}


task run(type: Exec) {
    def path
    def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
    if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        if (sdkDir) {
            path = sdkDir
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }

    def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'upwardteam.pavel.game/upwardteam.pavel.game.AndroidLauncher'
}

// sets up the Android Eclipse project, using the old Ant based build.
eclipse {
    // need to specify Java source sets explicitly, SpringSource Gradle Eclipse plugin
    // ignores any nodes added in classpath.file.withXml
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
        }
    }

    jdt {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.6
        targetCompatibility = 1.6
    }

    classpath {
        plusConfigurations += [project.configurations.compile]
        containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'
    }

    project {
        name = appName + "-android"
        natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
        buildCommands.clear();
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
        buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
    }
}

// sets up the Android Idea project, using the old Ant based build.
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("src");
        scopes = [COMPILE: [plus: [project.configurations.compile]]]

        iml {
            withXml {
                def node = it.asNode()
                def builder = NodeBuilder.newInstance();
                builder.current = node;
                builder.component(name: "FacetManager") {
                    facet(type: "android", name: "Android") {
                        configuration {
                            option(name: "UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES", value: "true")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> android:processDebugResources FAILED

Means one of your XML resources is not correct.

There is a Gradle `lint` task that may help with that.

The Gradle panel of Android Studio should be on the right side of the screen.